# Move/Delete Emails in an Office 365 add-in

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-2013, office365-apps

I have an Outlook 2013 add-in that I'm developing.  Its very simple - it forwards the selected email as an attachment to a specific address and then it deletes the email selected.  (Really just moves it to the recycle bin).
If our organization upgrades to Office 365, is there anyway to replicate that functionality with the 'new' add-ins?  The javascript API's don't seem to give any way of moving emails to other folders or otherwise 'deleting' them.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185.aspx

Is there another method/API for developing add-ins for Outlook 365?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail Apps are run in the context of items and [JavaScript API for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185.aspx) doesn't provide any methods for that. You need to use EWS or [Office 365 API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog) for getting the job done. Also see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Comment: Ok, it appears I can use the Javascript API to create the actual plugin that the user can invoke.  Then I would be able to call the Mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161019.aspx (assuming my permissions are set up correctly) and use the EWS methods listed here under read/write mailbox permission:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
to do my moving and sending.
Does that sound about right?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I couldn't for the life of me find the EWS API.  Sounds like I can keep all the functionality with the combination of these two approaches.  Thank you!